# Replace standard errors with t values without affecting the default format

Tags: r, stargazer

I am learning to use stargazer to output regression tables. I've been trying to replace the standard errors (in parenthesis) with t values, and I tried the following codes:

```
f1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1 x2, data=mydata)

stargazer(f1, type="text", out="models.txt", report=('vc*t'))
```

The `report=('vc*t')` option does replace standard errors with t values. But it also removes the original parenthesis around the standard errors and adds "t=" in front of t values. Here are the coefficients and the t values when using `report=('vc*t')`:

```
-0.026***         
t = -3.681                                                          

0.002***          
t = 3.260
```

The ideal outputs should look like this:

```
-0.026***         
(-3.681)                                                          

0.002***          
(3.260)
```

I've also tried the `se` option:

```
stargazer(f1, type="text", out="models.txt", se=list(summary(f1)$coef[c(2:4,1),"t value"]))
```

But it appears to mess the "*" that indicates the significance level.

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were almost there. Since you passed stargazer a new argument for the standard errors, it will use those to calculate significance. Pass stargazer your original list of p-values, and you should be all set. Here's a complete example.

```
data(iris)
ols.result <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data = iris)
ols.t.stat <- summary(ols.result)$coef[ , "t value"]
ols.p.val  <- summary(ols.result)$coef[ , "Pr(>|t|)"]
stargazer(ols.result, se = list(ols.t.stat), p = list(ols.p.val))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I guess there is a typo in your example code: `ols.p.val  <- summary(results)$coef[ , "Pr(>|t|)"]` should be `ols.p.val  <- summary(ols.result)$coef[ , "Pr(>|t|)"]`

Comment: Sorry about that! I made the change!